# Redirect to a .html if from some domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have two domains that are pointing to the same directory, but I would like to redirect them (via `mod_rewrite` in `htaccess`) to some specific .html when hitting home.

Like:

```
if (domain == 'firstdomain')
redirect firstdomain.html
else if (domain == 'seconddomain')
redirect seconddomain.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [..] I would like to redirect them to some specific .html when hitting home.

A language like PHP is better suited for redirecting a single page.

The following code will redirect `http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/example.html` and `http://example.org/` to `http://example.org/anotherpage.html`. `http://www.example.com` will be unaffected (note the `www.` part)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ example.html [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ anotherpage.html [R]
```

The first line matches the HTTP Host field (a.k.a. 'domain') against `example.com` case-insensitive (`^` marks the beginning of the string, `$` marks the end).
If there is a match, the page will be redirected (second line, `[R]`) to `example.html`
The same story for the third and fourth lines.